# How to move turtles at the same time and how to avoid collision of turtles?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to represent a road intersection using turtle. To do that I need to move vehicles (turtles) from different directions at the same time. I found that ontimer() method can be used but it seems like not working in my case. here is the code

```
  dist_1 = random.randint(5,15)
  length_1 = 0
  while length_1<1:  
    for i in range(3):
      for j in range(3):
        vehicles_1[i][j].speed(0)
        vehicles_1[i][j].forward(dist_1)
        length_1 = vehicles_1[i][j].xcor()

  time.sleep(5)
  while length_1<200:  
    for i in range(3):
      for j in range(3):
        vehicles_1[i][j].forward(dist_1)
        length_1 = vehicles_1[i][j].xcor()
  screen.ontimer(Moving_vehicles_1, 100)

def Moving_vehicles_2(vehicles_2):
  dist_2 = random.randint(5,15)
  length_2 = 0
  while length_2>80:  
    for i in range(3):
      for j in range(3):
        vehicles_2[i][j].speed(0)
        vehicles_2[i][j].forward(dist_2)
        length_2 = vehicles_2[i][j].ycor()

  time.sleep(5)
  while length_2>-150:  
    for i in range(3):
      for j in range(3):
        vehicles_2[i][j].forward(dist_2)
        length_2 = vehicles_2[i][j].ycor()
  screen.ontimer(Moving_vehicles_2, 100)
```

so basically I am creating two sets of vehicles. they bith should move certain distance and stop for a while and again they should start moving. this should happen at the same time.

Also I need to avoid collision of turtles. if you how to do that please mention.

Please provide any solution or source links that you are aware of. thanks in advance.

edit 1: I got to know that NetLogo can be used to avoid collision but I actually don't know how to import that and use it.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to fix your code specifically suddenly, but if you want to move the turtle that doesn't collide, for example, you can also use the following code, which have the tortoise check the forward state and if it is vacant cell, then set it to 1 etc., using a variable of your choice, e.g. [set okgo 1] in this case. In the following ask statement, if the status of the okgo variable is 1, you can tell them it to go [forward 1]. This procedure must be carried out every ticks.

```
globals [okgo]
;omit

to go
  ask turtles with [xcor < max-pxcor][
    ifelse not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1
      [set okgo 1]
    [set okgo 0]
  ]

;omit

  ask turtles [if okgo = 1 ;
    [if not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1
      [forward 1]
  ]]
end
```