# netlogo: Minimum patch coordinate unit and monitoring availability?

Tags: coordinates, netlogo, patch

I would like to change the minimum coordinate unit of the patch space, which is set to exist only one turtle per patch space, to less than one, and monitor it. We want to set the minimum spatial unit to the same tick size n as in tick-advance (e.g. n=0.1). Here is a piece of code, but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
globals [n] ; n<=1 i.e. n=0.1
; omitted
ask turtles [forward n]
tick-advance n
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean by "which is set to exist only one turtle per patch space"? What do you mean by "set the minimum spatial unit"? Finally: what does it mean "it doesn't work"? Please be more specific: do you get an error message? Do you get unexpected behaviour? Can you provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that will let us see exactly what you are seeing? If I run code similar to the one you posted, I get no errors and no unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Matteo, thanks for the question. "which is set to exist only one turtle per patch space"? 　⇒Answer Normally NetLogo allows a lot of turtles in a patch, but my model is set to exist only one turtle per patch space.

Comment: @Matteo,   "set the minimum spatial unit"?  　⇒Answer In NetLogo, the minimum coordinate unit is 1 by default.  I would like to divide this into parts to build my model. For example, I want to change the coordinates (X, Y) = (1, 1) to 1/10 (X, Y) = (0.1, 0.1).

Comment: @Matteo, "it doesn't work"?　⇒Answer For example, when I set n=0.1, forward 0.1 and tick-advance 0.1, and the turtle advances 1/10 in the same patch, but the subsequent turtle does not enter the same patch. This can be illustrated by, for example... |  ●       |    ●     | ●        |     ●    | This is the not work well situation. I would like to reproduce the following situation. when I set n<1,
|●●●●●●●●●● |●●●●●●●●●●|●●●●●●●●●●|●●●●●●●●●●|

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I'm still a bit confused about the goal and the approach, so I think I'm not the right person to tackle this. Hopefully someone will come along with a better understanding of the problem than mine.

Comment: @Matteo, Roger;; please introduce me to someone else ^^;;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find myself in the same boat as Matteo- I don't know that what you're looking to do is possible / makes sense in the context of NetLogo. The coordinates of patches are fixed (ie, one patch is one unit) but arbitrary (1 in Netlogo can mean 1 m or 1 km, depending on the model). In other words, a patch's coordinates are discrete, while turtles can move around in continuous space. So you can, of course, have a turtle wander around in step sizes of 1/10:

```
globals [n]

to setup
  ca
  set n 0.1
  crt 10
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    forward n
  ]
  tick-advance n  
end
```

After one run of `go` above, you could conceivably have a turtle at coordinates `[xcor = 0.1, ycor = 0.1]`, although it would still be on `patch 0 0` since `pxcor` values are integers.

It seems that what you are actually needing to do is not coming across as needed- can you edit your question to provide a little more detail / context? Perhaps knowing the **why** behind your need to model in this way will help askers get you pointed in the right direction. I personally am curious about:

- Why you are using `tick-advance` instead of just `tick`
- How you have implemented your one-turtle-per-patch restrictions- in other words, can you show a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That may prompt other ways to approach what you're after.

---

Here is an example world with time tied to ticks:

```
globals [ seconds ]

to setup
  ca
  set seconds 0
  resize-world 0 50 0 50
  ask patches with [ 
    floor (pxcor / 10) mod 2 + floor (pycor / 10) mod 2 = 1
  ] [
    set pcolor white
  ]
  crt 10
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    fd 1
  ]
  set seconds precision (seconds + 0.1) 2
  if seconds mod 1 = 0 [print ( word "It has been " seconds " seconds.")]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments that you mention this > > In other words, a patch's coordinates are discrete, while turtles can move around in continuous space.  This is just what I am aiming and correctly intended to say. I am considering a physical model called TASEP (sorry for the jargon), which is a continuous approximate change of space for this test. But, it's failing with NetLogo,, How can I change the coordinates of a batch in a continuous (coordinate, x<1) way? Is this a limitation of the NetLogo specification?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68562296/how-to-move-turtles-at-the-same-time-and-how-to-avoid-collision-of-turtles/69015211#69015211  The code I wrote in this thread as a suggested answer is additional information for the Minimal Reproducible Example. Adding this code with the test model will result in a space where there is only one turtle per patch exists.

Comment: >>Why you are using tick-advance instead of just tick ⇒Answer The reason for this change is that I want to change to a continuous time model.

Comment: @goodgest "How can I change the coordinates of a batch in a continuous (coordinate, x<1) way? Is this a limitation of the NetLogo" -> Yes, as far as I know this is sort of a limitation in the sense that you mean- NetLogo patches cannot (as far as I know) have a "size" / "unit" *different* than 1.

Comment: @goodgest "I want to change to a continuous time model" -> Fair enough- but you are still using discrete units of time to simulate a continuous time model- I would personally just use the patch size as the size you 'want' and treat the tick itself as whatever time you want it to represent. Otherwise, I think you will be restricted by the way that the NetLogo world works (as far as I know!)

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! I'm sad that NetLogo can only handle such a discrete patch specification... Luke C, how do you model a continuous representation of a patch specification? Or do you not use NetLogo, Matlab?

Comment: Otherwise, it would be better to build a discrete time model with a discrete space model as foward 10, etc., and compare it with a continuous time model with a continuous space model (in this case, foward 1), right?

Comment: @goodgest - For my purposes I actually don't model anything that would benefit from a true 'continuous' world as I am typically dealing with remote imagery with pixel sizes from 5-25 meters. In such a case, although my model animals can move around in continuous space, the way we can represent the world means that the resolution is appropriate for my needs. Always important to remember that "All models are wrong, but some are useful!"

Comment: @goodgest "Otherwise, it would be better to..." - Depends on your needs, but that sounds like a reasonable approach if I understand it correctly- scale your patches and ticks to be representative of the space and time scales that work for your needs

Comment: Thank you very much your comments. I think so, too. I will try to experiment with this approach ^^/

Comment: @goodgest - You bet! I have also added a minor change to my answer to hopefully represent what I was trying to get at. Good luck!

Comment: I developed the model. So far, it's working. Thanks for your advice. Splendid!